# Symbolic matrix without bracket

Tags: matlab

Is there any way to make symbolic matrix without showing bracket in result?
IE: when we type

```
[1,2;3,4]
ans=
      1    2
      3    4
```

but when we type symbolic matrix it shows like this

```
[cos(x),-sin(x);sin(x),cos(x)]
ans=
[ cos(x), -sin(x)]
[ sin(x),  cos(x)]
```

is there any way to show like this

```
    cos(x)   -sin(x)
    sin(x)    cos(x)
```

without brackets.
I also tried 'disp' and typed each raw in it, but i wanna know is there any other way to do it?
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
syms x
h = sym([cos(x),-sin(x);sin(x),cos(x)]);
f = cell(2,2);
for k=1:4
  f(k) = {char(h(k))};
end
f
```

matlab r2015a

This results in

> 'cos(x)'    '-sin(x)'
>   'sin(x)'    'cos(x)'